# How best to work around Tensorflow 2.0 Embedding layer evident limitation of needing data encoded starting at 0 or 1?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

It's not documented, but pretty apparent that the following Embedding lookup failure is because TensorFlow is assuming incorrectly that my data begins at 0 or 1, but in fact it begins at 1997.  I foresee a couple of workarounds but none are very good.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[0,0] = 1998 is not in [0, 3)
     [[node MultiLatentFactorEmbeddings/B_rating_year/embedding_lookup (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_11141]

My data column rating_year has this data:
col_0        count
rating_year       
1997         47762
1998         42479
```

A Keras functional model design is being used here. My embedding layers look like this:

```
a = Embedding(input_dim=num_uniques[cn]+1, output_dim=emb_len_adj[cn], input_length=1, embeddings_regularizer=reg, name="E_" + cn)(emb_input)
```

What workaround has worked best for you? (I mean, other than using PyTorch or CNTK instead of Tensorflow 2.0).  3 possibilities are:

- Recode the entire column of data to start at 0 in data preprocessing code, by creating additional columns in the dataset that do so, for all columns that need recoding to keep TF2.0 happy. For large datasets, this can be memory- and time- challenging. Additional code to look up the original meaningful values is also needed, so you can understand the encodings that you are looking at.
- Simply use input_size=max(column)+1. This results in too many weights to train for no reason, reducing predictive performance and increasing the training time.  For appli9cations that use categorical embeddings extensively, this can be memory- and time-challenging, as well as worse predictive performance. **If you have a column with just 1997 and 1998 in it, like I actually do, consider how many useless trainable weights your embeddings layer will have if you naively follow the Keras TF 2.0 documentations to use "max(column)+1" as your Embedding layer's input_size.**
- Encode numeric columns as string. Then encode using 0-based as usual. Maybe this works? **I'd like to hear if you tried it. I don't foresee a downside yet except computations will be difficult on this column due to additional typecasting burden on the applicaton, and being sure to use the raw column not the encoded column for computations on this column.**

Is there a better way?

Background:  I was making and debugging a tensorflow 2.0 model because I saw PyTorch demos in 2018 doing extensive categorical embeddings in models in a Kaggle contest, very successfully (the Rossman contest). Sadly I think I discovered -- I certainly could be wrong and I would love to be shown how wrong I am -- they wrote Keras TensorFlow2.0 to seemingly assume NLP was going to be the only "embedding". That's where you, the app developer, gets to encode the text into numbers starting at 0. But in categorical embeddings the data is already given to you -- you often cannot create your own numerical encodings (or you can, but you have to also keep the original encoding around too as I explained). To be clear, string columns can and will be numerically encoded as 0-based but numeric columns will often not.

It's not only for NLP; embedding is more general than that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) of `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` class. It says it "turns **positive integers (indexes)** into dense vectors of fixed size", so you have to pass indexes(encodings) of your variable. Try using `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` to encode your variable more elegantly, regardless of type (string or integer)

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
values = [1997, 1998, 1998, 1999]
le.fit(values)
transformed_values = le.transform(values)
```

`transofrmed_values` will be equal to `array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)`. After that you can save the `le` variable using pickle and reuse it later in your application.